# Print form validation errors in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using [registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Django and cannot get the error codes to display inline when the wrong username or password is entered. Oddly enough, if either is left blank, it shows the error message for that. I have left out the password bit to make the example brief.

```
<form method="post" action="?next={{ next|default:" / " }}" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
            # HERE IS THE BIT THAT IS FAILING {% if form.username.errors %} {{ form.username.errors }} {% endif %} {{ form.username }}
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

Does anyone see  problem with what I am doing here? I also had the

`{{ form. username.errors }}` wrapped in a **p** tag but it didn't help.

Comment: Try: `{{ form.username.errors.0 }}` to print the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to the form:

```
<form method="post" action="?next={{ next|default:"/" }}" class="form-horizontal">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
...
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you.